# OCaml searchin longest increasing subsequence

Tags: list, ocaml

I try to find longest increasing subsequence in list.
And I have a problems with it ?
Any suggestions ?
For example

```
[-5;6;7;8;-1;6;7;8;9;10;11;12]
The answer should be [-1;6;7;8;9;10;11;12]
```

Comment: It is “OCaml”. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet of code answers your question, IMHO.

```
let longest l =
  let rec aux nbest best ncurr curr = function
    | [] -> List.rev best
    | hd :: tl when hd <= List.hd curr -> (* new sequence *)
        aux nbest best 1 [hd] tl
    | hd :: tl when nbest > ncurr ->
        aux nbest best (ncurr + 1) (hd :: curr) tl
    | hd :: tl ->
        aux (ncurr + 1) (hd :: curr) (ncurr + 1) (hd :: curr) tl
  in
  if l = [] then [] else aux 1 [List.hd l] 1 [List.hd l] (List.tl l)

let test = [-5; 6; 7; 8; -1; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12]

let () =
  List.iter (Printf.printf "%i ") (longest test)
```

Notice that it will return the first strictly increasing sequence, and that the nbest and ncurr are there only for performance reasons. I don't see any way of avoiding the List.rev operation. The function is tail-recursive.

Comment: I would rewrite the line `if l = [] then [] else aux 1 [List.hd l] 1 [List.hd l] (List.tl l)` by `match l with [] -> [] | hd::tl -> aux 1 [hd] 1 [hd] tl`.